# How does the regular expression match 3 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is a statement from JavaScript regular expression description:

> `^` has a different meaning when it appears as the first character in a character set pattern.
>   For example, `/[^a-z\s]/` matches the `'3'` in `"I have 3 sisters"`.

How does `^` match `3`?

Comment: I recommend you check out a good reference for the syntax basics: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~jbs/resources/perl/perl-basics/regular_expressions.html

Comment: Ankur is correct, though this is a somewhat convoulted method.  Matching numbers is as simple as `[0-9]` or `\d`. Perhaps the use case actually requires symbols be matched as well but that is not clear from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `^` opearator here means negation, it means that match any character which is not a space or alphabet(a-z). It will still match capital alphabets(A-Z)

You can refer this url: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for more information on regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple misunderstanding i guess. ^ does not match the '3'.  /[^a-z\s]/ matches the '3'.